# Run Latexian output with latexcalc

Tags: tools, latexian

I'm using Latexian to typeset my documents, and also another tool called [latexcalc](http://latexcalc.sourceforge.net/)(check it out, its really useful!) , which automatically evaluates the result of typeset calculations. Is there some way I can hook the `latexcalc` binary into `pdflatex` so they both work seamlessly through Latexian?

The command Latexian uses is:

```
/usr/texbin/pdflatex --interaction nonstopmode --shell-escape --file-line-error /Users/ankit/Documents/Classes/10601/hw2/TSWLatexianTemp_hw2.tex
```

and the command for `latexcalc` is:

```
latexcalc --pdflatex ~/Documents/Classes/10601/hw2/hw2.tex
```

I suppose I could configure Latexian to use the `latexcalc` binary directly, but the logging output (among other things?) might not work correctly.

Comment: Not to dismiss LaTeXcalc but why not simply using `calc` or any other math package? and i can sense an arara answer for this.

Comment: See [How to customize Latexian to use other TeX engines or biber?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/183884) for a solution that allows Latexian to use `arara`, which can (I assume) run `latexcalc`.

Answer (score 3):

At present I'd say there is not an easy way to achieve this with Latexian, although with other tools it should be doable. The best approach in general is to create a script of some form which runs `latexcalc` followed by `pdflatex` (or other engine). That's quite doable, and there are several options. However, Latexian doesn't allow you to pick/add individual executables, it only lets you choose a path to find the binaries of *e.g.* MacTeX. As such, there is no way to add a custom tool like the script you want. That would be a feature request for the editor.