# How to customize Latexian to use other TeX engines or biber?

Tags: luatex, compiling, biber, editors, latexian

The Mac editor Latexian has built in methods for compiling using `latex+dvips`, `pdflatex` and `xelatex`.  Furthermore, it assumes `bibtex` and `makeindex` to deal with bibliographies and indexes, respectively.

How do I customize Latexian to use, e.g. LuaTeX for compiling or Biber for bibliographies?

Comment: See also [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Comment: @moewe Should I copy my answer there too?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just happened to stumble across this question and thought I might add the link such that both questions are (... well ...) linked. Since your question here uses arara it might not be of exactly the kind the other question is after, but if you would add a n explanation as to how to set up Biber with Latexian in the other question that would be awesome.

Comment: @moewe  Unless LaTeXian has changed, using `arara` is the only way to do it.

Comment: Ahhh - I hadn't actually read your answer thoroughly, never mind then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way Latexian is written, the built-in methods cannot be changed with any user preference.  This is, in my opinion, a serious design flaw, but it's not too hard to create a workaround for this limitation.

The workaround has two components: a script which is put in a local folder and which replaces (from Latexian's point of view) one or more of the three TeX engines that Latexian knows about. The script bypasses those engines and instead uses the `arara` automation tool instead to control all compilation.  By using `arara` you can then specify with very fine control the exact compilation chain you need on a document by document basis.

### Introduction to arara

In order to make sense of how this works you first need to understand `arara`.  `arara` allows you to add comments to your document which tell it how to compile that document.  A simple use would be the following:

```
% arara: pdflatex
```

which would tell `arara` to process the document with `pdflatex`.  A slightly more complicated example (but conceptually as simple) would be:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
```

This would compile a document, run `bibtex` and then compile it twice more to resolve the references.

From these small examples, it should be clear that *all* of the binaries available in MacTeX will be available to `arara`, which means that if we can get Latexian to use `arara` we can get Latexian to use any TeX binary.  We turn to this task next.

### Getting Latexian to use arara

First we create a local folder which we will point Latexian to.  You can do this with the Finder or the Terminal.  In this example, we will call the folder `latexian-bin`.

```
mkdir ~/latexian-bin
```

In a text editor, create the following file:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}

arara -v "${@:$#}"
```

Save this as `arara` in the `latexian-bin` folder.  You must make the file executable, so in a Terminal window, type:

```
cd ~/latexian-bin
chmod +x arara
```

Finally, make symbolic links to this script for the `xelatex` and `pdflatex` binaries Latexian knows about. Then make symbolic links to the real `latex` and `dvips` (otherwise Latexian will always return an error when using this `latex+dvips`.)

```
ln -s arara pdflatex
ln -s arara xelatex
ln -s /Library/TeX/texbin/latex latex
ln -s /Library/TeX/texbin/dvips dvips
ln -s /Library/TeX/texbin/synctex synctex
```

Now within Latexian, go to the Preferences and choose Preview.  In this preference you can choose the Folder for TeX Distribution. By default, this is set to `/Library/TeX/texbin` (`/usr/texbin/` in older MacTeX distributions) but we now want Latexian to use the local folder we created.  Use the Browse button to select the `latexian-bin` folder.  If you have done things correctly, you should see the following:

[image: Preferences screen shot]

Your actual path will be different from `/Users/alan/latexian-bin` but should look similar.  Don't worry that some of the other binaries are x-ed out and say "Not found". This doesn't actually matter.

You now have a pointed LaTeXian to its own local binary folder, and now instead of compiling with `pdflatex` you will be compiling with `arara`.  Now for every document you need to provide the correct `arara` lines at the top of the file to instruct it which binaries to use for that file.

For a basic `pdflatex` file you should use:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: yes }
```

For `xelatex`

```
% arara: xelatex: { synctex: yes }
```

For `lualatex`

```
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: yes }
```

To also compile your file with `bibtex` add:

```
% arara: bibtex
```

To compile instead with `biber` add:

```
% arara: biber
```

This is all you need to do.

### Notes on implementation

Using this method you do not need to ever use the Latexian preferences to specify number of compilations or the subsidiary programs `bibtex` and `makeglossaries` or `makeindex`; these can all be done through `arara`.

If you don't want to use `arara` for all compilations, you can just link either the `pdflatex` or `xelatex` command to the `arara` script and the other command to its normal binary in `/Library/TeX/texbin`.  You can then use Latexian's GetInfo menu item to choose the one or the other for each file.  This may be the most practical solution if you mainly use one engine most of the time, since using `arara` will be slightly slower than using the engine directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I think a ":" is missing after pdflatex. The code line should be                                                                                      % arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}  If I'm right may be you can edit your answer.

Comment: @nik Thanks for catching that. I've fixed the answer.